# bubble in BING MAP in windows Store app + c#

Tags: c#, pushpin

[image]

I am using this code:

```
          var highway1 = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(uri) };
            highway1.Width = wH;
            highway1.Height = wH;
          //  highway1.Tapped += pushpinTapped;
            MapLayer.SetPosition(highway1, new Location(5.3538, 101.35885));
            highway1.Tag = highway1.Tag as String;
            highway1.Tag = "jkhdfhdskjfhjsakhfkjajskdf";
            map1.Children.Add(highway1);
```

How can I do this in Bing maps using C#. I manage to do this using Geoserver.

Thanks